# Saiku and Drupal

Tags: java, drupal, olap

I've been browsing through the web but haven't been able to find any concrete topics on the integration of [Saiku](http://analytical-labs.com/) with Drupal. The main challenge seems to be that Saiku is java-based while Drupal runs off PHP.

I am wondering if anyone has implemented, or can provide thoughts on this union.

Is there anything similar to Saiku that would work with Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A developer of Saiku could answer you better than me but what I can say is that communication between Saiku-ui and Saiku is REST, so it is pure utilization of HTTP protocol. An integration could be an independent SAIKU server, Drupal relaying requests from the embedded UI inside your content.
Saiku is based on Mondrian, which is also a java library, but it can be deployed as an independent XMLA server. So you could recode Saiku REST services in PHP, which would call the XMLA services.

Answer (score 1):

Well then a developer of Saiku shall answer:

Saiku UI is completely separated from the server and plain JavaScript and HTML, so it would be easy to integrate that somehow into drupal. basically you just need to drop the UI folder into drupal and configure where the server lives (to avoid cross domain issues it would be good if saiku server was connected via mod_jk or mod_proxy on the same apache as drupal runs)

if you want to leverage saiku as olap backend with custom PHP code, there is a framework developed by inovia called PHPAnalytics, that is using saiku server as a backend: http://labs.inovia.fr/phpanalytics/

Answer (score 0):

Although Saiku UI use jquery and html at client side, it still need a restful service sit on top of OLAP engine at back end. The restful server provided by saiku package is java based, just like jpivot and pentatho analyzer. So if you want to integrate it with drupal, either you need to write your own PHP restful service, or you need proxy to another java based service in drupal server.

There is a pure javascript solution at [webpivottable.com](http://webpivottable.com) which provide excel pivot table-like UI to pivot all kinds of OLAP cubes. It's totally at client side and connect to XMLA service directly, so no back end dependencies. You can give it a try and it can easily to be integrated to any web site and web application. Here is a [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo)